# How can i change the value of data-rules-required using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I am using a validiation script on my website like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Abomonatspreis" name="Abomonatspreis" form="formular" data-rules-required="true">
```

In some case i have to change the data-rules-required value to "false" using jQuery.

I tried it this way, but it did not work:

```
$("#Abomonatspreis").attr({data-rules-required: "false"})
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Thank you
Ingo

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. This is a trivial task for the DOM API:

```js
document.getElementById('Abomonatspreis').dataset.rulesRequired = "false";

console.log(document.getElementById('Abomonatspreis').outerHTML);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Abomonatspreis" name="Abomonatspreis" form="formular" data-rules-required="true">
```

Instead of working with the `dataset` object, you could as well work with the HTML attribute. Both are synced automatically, meaning if you change either, you also change the other implicitly.

```
document.getElementById('Abomonatspreis').setAttribute('data-rules-required', 'false');
```

The reason your attempt failed is that you need to quote the attribute name, otherwise the `-` between the parts is considered the `minus` operator.

If you insist on using a third party library for trivial tasks, here's the jQuery version:

```js
$("#Abomonatspreis").attr({"data-rules-required": "false"})

console.log($("#Abomonatspreis")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Abomonatspreis" name="Abomonatspreis" form="formular" data-rules-required="true">
```